# Manage Complex types in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following entity models. When I try to save a new User object that contains a new Account, it throws a DBUpdateException: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships.

Is it possible to provide mapping for the two objects without adding foreign keys to my model. I hate the idea of having foreign keys in my models.
If there is no other solution, how would i resolve this issue using foreign keys?

```
public class User
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is possible in EF, navigation properties are strongly tied to FKs. CF my article on navigation properties here for how to do this WITH FKs http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/7/17/entity_framework-navigation_property_basics_with_code_first

Comment: @LukeMcGregor How do I setup the foreign keys? What is the naming conventions? Where is the generated database stored? I want to know how it's creating the tables, and relationships.

Comment: Check out my article, i go into all of those questions (except maybe where its stored, which is in the location defined by your connection string? is that what you mean?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are either of these classes really "complex types" or are they both entities with their own corresponding table?

If they're entities, you can indeed configure EF to not require foreign key properties in the classes themselves. In your DbContext class, override `OnModelCreating` and add some configuration code like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(u => u.Account).WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

If I've gotten that right, that will configure a "required:required" relationship between User and Account without needing any foreign key properties on either class.

Comment: That would be up to me, because I just started the application, and I haven't created any tables. The tables are automatically generated by Entity. Is it better to have multiple entities? or a complex type? what is the difference? Thanks

Comment: A complex type will put the properties of that class into the same table. So any properties you added to "Account", for example, would end up in the "Users" table. It's handy for things like addresses where you can wrap up street name, town, postcode etc into a class but not have those properties split out into a separate table.

Comment: Would that not be a bad choice, and cause performance problem on large datasets? Which one is the preferred option?

Comment: It's very much one of those "it depends" things, @aryaxt. If you know there will always been an Account record for every user, you might want to lump all the properties into the same table and turn Account into a complex type. If you do want that, remove the Id property from the Account class as per Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the property `Id` from your class `Account` otherwise the Entity Framework will treat the class `Account` as an entity and not as a complex type.